# password_verify returning false with correct password

Tags: php, passwords, verify

So I am trying to verify the hashed password of the user from MySQL DB but `password_verify` doesn't seem to be working. I feel like maybe it is something I am doing wrong.

Hashing and Storing the Password:

```
// Set POST variables
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$hashedpwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// SQL query & Error Handlers
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users_admin` (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$hashedpwd')";
```

Retrieving the Hashed Password:

```
 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $user_pass = $row['Password'];
        $passwordCheck = password_verify($password, $user_pass);
        if (!$passwordCheck) {
            header("Location: ../login.php?wrong-password");
            exit();
        } elseif ($passwordCheck) {
            // log in the user
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['ID'];
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['Firstname'];
            $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['Lastname'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['Email'];
            header("Location: ../dashboard");
            exit();

        }
    }
```

> `password_verify = bool(true)`

## EDIT:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include('DB_Connect.php');

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

// error handlers
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_admin WHERE Email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck < 1) {
    header("Location: ../login.php?input:invalid");
    exit();
} else {
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $user_pass = $row['Password'];
        $passwordCheck = password_verify($password, $user_pass);
        if (!$passwordCheck) {
            header("Location: ../login.php?wrong-password");
            exit();
        } elseif ($passwordCheck) {
            // log in the user
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['ID'];
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['Firstname'];
            $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['Lastname'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['Email'];
            header("Location: ../dashboard");
            exit();

         }
     }
  }
}else{
    header("Location: ../login.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I would store my password with `bcrypt` --  This is currently the standard for password storage ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: Don't hash an escaped value. You should use prepared statements rather than escaping your input values, but if you're going to do it this way at least don't escape it before hashing it.

Comment: @Zak He is already using bcrypt. `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` uses bcrypt

Comment: Hi, I've made the final edit to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing on the code you posted that leads to the problem described.

Here are some hints and improvements:

### 1.

You are escaping/sanityzing the password before hashing it.

This way you're altering the stored password

Let

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

both when you create the account and when you check if the password match at login.

### 2.

Ensure the `Password` field in the database (that stores the hashed password) is able to store up to 255 characters.

From the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

> it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

If the field is narrower the hash will be truncated and you'll never have a match.

### 3.

As you get the user by **email** at login ensure that `Email` is unique (as long as your primary key `ID`) at database level (in the table definition).

Good idea to check this also upon user registration and login (at php level).

### 4.

Keys in the Key-Value pairs returned by `mysqli_fetch_assoc` are **case sensitive**. Ensure you access the values using keys written exactly as the field are named in the database.

Ex. in your code I read `$row['Email']`. In the table is the field name actually `Email` or maybe it's `email` (lowercase) ?

### 5.

**Debug your code!**

Use a debugger or simply place a breakpoint like

```
var_export( $the_variable );
exit();
```

in "key" points of your code.

### 6.

Use **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of escaping input and injecting it directly into the SQL strings.

---

**Hashing and Storing the Password:**

```
// Set POST variables
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hashedpwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// SQL query & Error Handlers
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users_admin` (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$hashedpwd')";
```

---

**Retrieving the Hashed Password:**

```
include('DB_Connect.php');

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_admin WHERE Email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if( $result === false )
{
    header("Location: ../login.php?login=error");
    exit();
}

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if( $count === 0 )
{
    header("Location: ../login.php?input:invalid");
    exit();
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );

$passwordHash = $row['Password'];
$passwordCheck = password_verify( $password, $passwordHash );
if( ! $passwordCheck )
{
    header("Location: ../login.php?wrong-password");
    exit();
}

// log in the user
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['ID'];
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['Firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['Lastname'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['Email'];
header("Location: ../dashboard");
exit();
```

Comment: So remove the `mysqli_real_escape_string` only?

Comment: Still returning false

Comment: "*Still returning false*" you have to store the password again. You did it?

Comment: I did store the password again

Comment: Still returns as false

Comment: I added the full record fetch

Comment: Is `Email` unique? If you `var_export($resultCheck); exit()` do you get `1` ?

Comment: I have unique emails. The site isn't being used by the end user right now

Comment: @MwikalaKangwa also, ensure the size of the `Password` field is at least 60 characters. Better 255.

Answer (score 1):

Paolo's answer is good and answers your question, I just wanted to explain to you why your passwords *are not the same*.

First, you take the POSTed password and escape it:

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
```

And then you hash **the escaped password**:

```
$hashedpwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

But here:

```
$passwordCheck = password_verify($password, $user_pass);
```

You `password_verify` **the unescaped password** (I assume as you didn't publish the full code)

To solve this issue, do not escape the password, a better solution as Paolo suggested in his answer is to use Prepared Statement.

Comment: Yeah I have hashed the entered the password not the escaped password now but I still get it returning false

Comment: Don't know if Mwikala has solved the problem but I've the same. I create password automaticly and some times I have some for which password_verify is returning false.